# Vue router have not seen store state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application, vuex, vue-router

My Vue app is using a vue-router and vuex. I get a auth token from my API and I push token to localStorage and my store. When page is refreshing, app is loading token from localStorage and push it to store. In my router I created guard:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.auth)) {
        if (store.getters.logged) {
            if (to.meta.scope === store.getters.scope){
                next();
                return;
            }else{
                next({name: 'forbidden'});
                return;
            }
        }
        next({name: 'login'});
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

but the guard is not working correctly because vue-router is loading before vuex so store is empty and my scope is undefined Guard redirect all request to forbidden. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: There's no issue accessing a store in router. You either have implemented one of them wrongly or, more likely, the logic to get the token from localStorage goes through a store action. Store actions are async which means that even when the token is in localStorage the execution of the action is pushed to the end of the execution queue. So the router `beforeEach` will run before it. One way to fix it is to await the execution of your store's action inside router's beforeEach. In order not to delay every route change, only do this when the token is not present in the store.

Comment: If you need more help, you might want to provide a *runnable* [mcve]. Consider using codesandbox.io or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this problem is in implementation of saving\retrieving store from localStorage. I suggest you to not re-invent the wheel and use this package instead which will solve your problem:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // ...
  plugins: [createPersistedState()]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try import store before router like

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
import App from './App.vue';
new Vue({ 
    store,
    router,
    render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```